# Using WriteAllText How To Write DataTable Column Names To CSV File

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and am using WriteAllText to write contents of a DataTable to a csv file.  Everything works as I expect **EXCEPT** the header information, which should be the DataTable column names.

How do I write the DataTable column names as my header?

```
private void GenerateRETest()
{
    DataTable rI = new DataTable();
    rI.Columns.Add("sID", typeof(int));
    rI.Columns.Add("sn", typeof(string));
    rI.Columns.Add("RE", typeof(string));
    rI.Rows.Add(25, "Apex 1", "RE 1");
    rI.Rows.Add(50, "Apex 2", "RE 1");
    rI.Rows.Add(10, "Apex 3", "RE 1");
    rI.Rows.Add(21, "Apex 4", "RE 1");
    rI.Rows.Add(251, "Apex 11", "RE 11");
    rI.Rows.Add(501, "Apex 21", "RE 11");
    rI.Rows.Add(101, "Apex 31", "RE 11");
    rI.Rows.Add(211, "Apex 41", "RE 11");
    rI.Rows.Add(215, "Apex 12", "RE 12");
    rI.Rows.Add(510, "Apex 22", "RE 12");
    rI.Rows.Add(110, "Apex 32", "RE 12");
    rI.Rows.Add(211, "Apex 42", "RE 12");

    var columnNames = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy((sn) => sn.Field<string>("RE"))
                                        .Select((group) => new
                                        {
                                            RE = group.Key,
                                            DataRowList = group.OrderBy((dataRow) => dataRow.Field<string>("sn")).ToList()
                                        }).OrderBy(x => x.RE).ToList();

    foreach (var row in columnNames)
    {
        foreach (var dataRow in row.DataRowList)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
            IEnumerable<string> fields = dataRow.ItemArray.Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)) + "\\" + row + "display.csv";
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to have *one* StringBuilder, declared outside the loop, so you'll still have it after the loop when you want to write the whole thing to the file (as it is, you create a new one each time through the loop and then throw it away without using the text you appended to it). You want to add the header row to the StringBuilder *once*, before the loop, so the header row will precede the rows. You want to call `sb.Append()` when you add fields to a line, and only call `sb.AppendLine()` when you want to complete the line and start a new one.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - I originally had my code with the StringBuilder decleration and the sb.AppendLine outside of the foreach loop.  However, when I had the code written in that manner all data was being written to each RE csv file instead of only data relevant for that specific RE.

Comment: Are you trying to write one fine for each column name? I see two loops here. Your columnname variable is named `row`. Please clearly explain what you are trying to accomplish. In any case, if you throw away a StringBuilder and never write its contents to any file, you should expect that its contents will not appear in any of your files.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - I am wanting to generate a csv file for each RE listed in the datatable.  When the code finishes processing, I want 3 csv files named RE1, RE11, RE12 and each file having a header row of: sID, sn, RE and the corresponding data from the rows in the datatable in the csv file.  The csv files are being generated appropriately, just the header is not being written to the file.

Comment: So you want to create one file for each dataRow in row.DataRowList?

Comment: One file for each unique value in the column RE of the DataTable.

Comment: Do you really want your files to be named `{ RE = RE 12, DataRowList = System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.Data.DataRow] }display.csv`?

Comment: No.  I want the file to be named whatever the value of RE is.  So the 3 files should be named: RE1, RE11, RE12

Comment: `row` is an instance of the anonymous type from your LINQ expression. Did you use the debugger at all?

Comment: Yes, I did use the debugger.  I was still stepping through the code and attempting to resolve this issue on my own.  I *think* i'll be able to achieve this one :0\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here. I've improved the naming. I've put the StringBuilder declaration and the header row in the outer loop: As I explained above, you only want one header row per file. You don't want to repeat the header row for every row in the file. For each file, you want to start with a fresh StringBuilder, append the header row to it exactly once, append multiple lines to it, then write the whole mess to the file. The outer loop is one file, so that's the natural scope for the StringBuilder.

Your code was trying to concatenate the entire contents of `columnNames` for the header row, but `columnNames` was a collection of anonymous-typed objects that stringified as `{ RE = RE 12, DataRowList = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataRow] }`. Then you put one of them in your filename.`columnNames` is a good choice for a collection of names of columns, but not for what you had there.

```
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy((sn) => sn.Field<string>("RE"))
            .Select((group) => new
            {
                RE = group.Key,
                DataRowList = group.OrderBy((dataRow) => dataRow.Field<string>("sn")).ToList()
            }).OrderBy(x => x.RE).ToList();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName)));

    foreach (var dataRow in group.DataRowList)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = dataRow.ItemArray.Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
    }
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)) 
        + "\\display-RE" + group.RE + ".csv";
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());
}
```